# Replacing a local javascript array with JSON and AJAX

Tags: json, ajax

I am in the process of integrating an interactive quiz on my website. I did stumble upon a working quiz but I would like to use AJAX along side an external JSON file to retrieve the questions and answers as an array. My html makes 2 calls

```
     <script src="question.js"></script>
     <script src="quiz-script.js"></script>
```

question.js contains the following

```
  var questions = [{
  "question": "The first mechanical computer designed by  Charles       
  Babbage was called ?",
  "option1": "Abacus",
  "option2": "Analytical Engine",
  "option3": "Calculator",
  "option4": "Processor",
  "answer": "2"
  }, {
  "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of 
  computer ?",
  "option1": "Super-micro",
  "option2": "Super conductor",
  "option3": "Super computer",
  "option4": "Megaframe",
  "answer": "3"
  }]
```

The following modification for question.js:

```
   var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.rockmissionary.org/quiz- 
   data.json', true);
   ourRequest.onload = function() {
   var questions = ourRequest.responseText;
   console.log(questions);
   };
   ourRequest.send();
```

returns the following error ----- ReferenceError: questions is not defined. 
Please help.

Comment: Is the html page that runs this code deployed at www.rockmissionary.org ?

Comment: No. It is not. It is locally tested.

Answer (score 1):

The above code works when formatted correctly. It might just be a copy/paste issue. See below for better formatting:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://www.rockmissionary.org/quiz-data.json");

xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function solved it. Thanks to everyone who contributed in any away to help me solve this very simple issue. What would we do without  **stackoverflow**?

```
    function getJSONData(jsonurl) {
    var req = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) { }
        }
    }
    req.open('GET', 'quiz-data.json', false);
    req.send(null);
    return req.status == 200 ? req.responseText : 'Error occurred';
    }
    var questions = JSON.parse(getJSONData('quiz-data.json'));
```